# informatica cloud REST API content encoding UTF-8 error

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

When entering a port in the URL while using REST based Application integration I am getting below error:

*org.activebpel.rt.AeException: Content Encoding UTF-8 is not supported. The supported one is gzip.
at org.activebpel.rt.http.message.AeExtendedHttpResponse.getContent(AeExtendedHttpResponse.java:471)
at org.activebpel.rt.http.message.AeExtendedHttpResponse.consume(AeExtendedHttpResponse.java:227)
at org.activebpel.rt.http.AeHttpSendHandlerBase.deliver(AeHttpSendHandlerBase.java:153)
at org.activebpel.rt.http.handler.AeHttpPostHandler.prepareAndDeliver(AeHttpPostHandler.java:59)
at org.activebpel.rt.http.handler.AeHttpPostHandler.handle(AeHttpPostHandler.java:38)*

The URL & port used in binding is as below:
https://ais-py.companyxyz.com:83/jderest/tokenrequest

Comment: That link doesn't work. Please could you provide details of what exactly it is you are doing and what you have configured?

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry i can't post the actual URL as that will require me to seek permission from the client.  The issue is regardless of the URL I use, if i enter the port i.e :83 or any other port, the service starts to throw above error otherwise it works fine.

Comment: The issue is resolved, the error was in the response header which had Content Encoding as UTF-8 (which is incorrect value for Content Encoding, UTF-8 is charset value)